# Where can I store URL that is protected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, url, iframe

I have a list of buttons on my page and when the button is clicked a different report will show using a IFrame.

**I have a piece of Java code that gets passed a URL and sets that URL to the IFrame.**

```
<script>
    function setURL(url) {
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
    }
</script>
```

**Then on my buttons i have a 'OnClick' event that passes a URL to that Java code.**

```
<li><a onclick="setURL('URL I HAVE IS PLACED HERE')"><span>Audit</span></a></li>
```

The problem is I dont want to store my URL in my .aspx page as its not secure. Is there a place i can store these URL's and pass them on click?

Comment: whatever passed to client can be viewed/read by client. but you can obfuscate or encrypt the url and pass it to client then, at the time of action you can decrypt and use it.

Comment: @CerlinBoss At the time of use when the it will be decrypted would you still be able to see the URL

Comment: Yes. As i said anything passed to client is readable.

Comment: @CerlinBoss Is there a way i can store it somewhere else? Like web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET Sessions, but you need to change your onclick mechanism from client-side to server-side.

[More information](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp)